# mruby equivalent of begin ... end until

Tags: ruby, equivalent, mruby

I'm trying to port a ruby code base to mruby. In ruby (MRI), I can do (and unfortunately, the person who wrote it did)

```ruby
begin
  statement
end until condition
```

which executes `statement` once until and then until `condition` becomes positive. In mruby, however, the behavior is different, and the condition is evaluated before the first run, so this is equivalent to a `while` statement. What is the least intrusive alternative to this construct in mruby?

On a side note, is it possible to patch mruby so that this (and other) behavior becomes similar? I mean is there an existing set of patches that do this?

Comment: MRuby closely follows the ISO Ruby Language Specification. In general, as soon as you write code that depends on behavior that is outside the ISO specification, you are on your own.

Comment: @JörgWMittag fully agree. Unfortunately, people do write such code and others are forced to deal with it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loop` with `break` would probably work:

```
loop do
  statement
  break if condition
end
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this :P

Comment: `break if condition` is equivalent to `raise StopIteration if condition`, but is not if `break` takes an argument (e.g., `break x if condition`).